# Comparing elements inside array of ranges

Tags: ruby, data-structures

So given that I have this array of ranges:

```
[
    [0] Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:59:59 PST -08:00,
    [1] Mon, 29 Dec 2014 12:30:01 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:00:00 PST -08:00,
    [2] Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 08:59:59 PST -08:00,
    [3] Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:30:01 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:00:00 PST -08:00
]
```

How do I compare ranges that have the same minimum value and remove that element if the maximum value is greater than the other?

Comment: There are a couple of approachs you could use. One is to `group_by` the beginning of the range and then for each group keep the range whose end value is smallest. Another is to `sort_by` `[r.first, -r.last]`, then merge these values into an initially-empty hash.

Comment: I decided to provide an answer that implemented the two approaches I suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, where `a` is the array of ranges:

**#1**

```
a.each_with_object({}) { |r,h| h.update({ r.first=>r }) { |_,ov,nv|
  [ov,nv].min_by(&:last) } }.values
```

**#2**

```
a.group_by(&:first).values.map { |r| r.min_by(&:last) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, this will be slow:

```
your_array.group_by do |range|
  range.min
end.each do |min_value, ranges|
  least_max = ranges.map(&:max).min
  ranges.delete_if{ |range| range.max != least_max }
end.values
```

The following might be faster and also will delete things from your original array:

```
min_maxes = {}

your_array.each do |range|
  min = range.min
  max = range.max

  if min_maxes[min].nil? || (min_maxes[min] > max)
    min_maxes[min] = max 
  end
end

your_array.delete_if do |range|
  min_maxes[range.min] < range.max
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is  multimap data structure we can handle this scenario easily.  It is a hashing implementation using binary tree and elements are ordered in keys. And it allows duplicate keys. It is there in C++, not sure is there anything similar in Ruby. Since question tagged 'data structure' hopefully my answer spread some lights.

For your case, you can consider lower range as key and upper range as value. If there is a collision in lower range you can easily identify that and compare the values of collided records and delete one if necessary.